# "on the drive home" / "while I was driving home"?

Tags: word-choice, words, colloquial-language

How can I say "on the drive home"? I could come up with 帰り道に but this really doesn't give any information about the fact that I was driving.

> "Thinking about it made me still smile while I was driving home."

So one of my attempts at it would be

> あれを考えて、帰り道にニコニコしちゃったよ。

But the problems with this are that for one, I lost the "still" and for another I am not sure this sentence is even correct Japanese.... and is あれ really a natural way to refer to "it/that"?

Another attempt would be:

> あれを考えて、帰り道までにニコニコしちゃったよ。

or

> あれを考えて、帰り道にもニコニコしちゃったよ。

Comment: I would gladly post an answer if I did not have to discuss the phrase 「あれを考えてニコニコしちゃう」.  I am way too bashful to do that.  Wish you had not said it three times.

Comment: In fact, answering your primary question and correcting grammatical errors are easy, but making it into a natural passage would take a lot of work...

Comment: I believe that, in the abstract, you use the phrase "while I was driving home" to mean "my work day was over" because in the USA everyone drives home to the suburbs, right? But, I suspect a Japanese person might key on the "driving" part of "while I was driving home" because driving is an unusual way to get home. And, surely the act of "driving" has nothing to do with your "smiling", so I'd eliminate "driving" just make the sentence crisper and to the point. I think that "帰ってきた" signals "the work day is over".

Comment: @l'électeur Bashful? I don't understand. あれ here refers to an お世辞 I was told earlier that day. どう見てもお世辞だから笑っちゃう！

Comment: @broccoliforest I had no idea it was so difficult to say something seemingly so simple > . <

Comment: @David_W. 帰って来た unfortunately doesn't work here because I wasn't smiling after I entered the house but rather while I was still driving home ^^

Comment: 変なことを言っちゃったの？(T_T)

Comment: @user213845 Nope, I think it's just his heart is tainted :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to explicitly include everything — "to home", "to return/go back" and "to drive" — you have to say "運転して家に帰る途中". But 家に is usually obvious, and can be omitted.

ニコニコする in this context sounds a bit funny to me. The common and handy word for this is [思い出し笑い](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E6%80%9D%E3%81%84%E5%87%BA%E3%81%97%E7%AC%91%E3%81%84), and the most common mimesis of 思い出し笑い is ニヤニヤ, not ニコニコ. ニヤニヤ is used both when one suddenly recalls some very funny joke, and when one recalls some happy news.

Using あれ/それ is not bad, but あのこと or そのこと may sound a bit neater.

- 運転して帰る途中も、まだ思い出し笑いをしてたよ。
- 運転して家に帰る間も、あのことを思い出してニヤニヤが止まらなかったよ。

Comment: I see, the "still" becomes まだ in Japanese \(^o^)/

Answer (score 1):

As @naruto's answer already gives one of the best solutions based on your principle, I'd just like to show an example what *I* would naturally say it in Japanese, for your reference:

> おかげで、帰りの車の中でまでニヤニヤしてたもん。

Apparently it's too hot today to explain how I've transformed your original English into mine.

Comment: Thank you! I like the おかげで。I think I might produce a fusion sentence using both of the answers I received.